# Monit only executing once

Tags: monit

Monit is currently executing once. I can see in the log file that it does a check every cycle, however, the execution only happens once when I reload monit.

```
check host somehost with address example.com
# every "* 8-19 * * 1-5"
 if failed
    port 443
    protocol https
    and certificate valid > 1095 days
 then exec "/var/local/bin/mtCert.sh"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how monit is designed to operate. See  https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html

> The program is executed only once if the test fails. You can enable
>   execute repetition if the error persists for a given number of
>   cycles.

Adding `repeat every cycle` should satisfy your requirements. Note the same is true for alerts.